# How to change the default name of file to share in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

everyone!
I'm new in Swift and I've run into a problem.

I have an app that show images and I want to share some. When I click "share icon" there is default name "JPEG image". How can I change it to something like "defaultImageName".

[Image I want to share](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFB36.jpg)

[Share using default share in iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyytz.png)

[And here's default name that I want to change "JPEG image"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOU4t.png)

I've tried something like

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "defaultImageName")
```

But it's not correct, cause `imageView.image` it's not that I want to change.

Here's my code. I think it should be in `@objc func shareTapped()`, but don't really know how to do it.

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
    var selectedImage: String?
    var pictures = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    title = "Picture \(pictures.firstIndex(of: selectedImage!)!+1) of \(pictures.count)"
    navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .never //
    
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(shareTapped))
    
    if let imageToLoad = selectedImage {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: imageToLoad)
    }
    
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = false
}

@objc func shareTapped() {
    guard let image = imageView.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.8) else {
        print("No image found")
        return
    }
    
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [image], applicationActivities: [])
    
    vc.popoverPresentationController?.barButtonItem = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
    present(vc, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: Save the image with a filename of your choice in a temporary directory then share this file (instead of directly sharing the image).

Comment: @EricAya I don't really know how to Create temporary directory, as I said I'm new in Swift. Can you explain me that?